# CSS: position an `img` relative to a floating `li`

Tags: html, css

i am displaying a list of profiles using:

```
 <ul>
 <li>
    <p>Score: <span class="score">33</span> | Depuis: 1333</p>
    <p class="username">
         <a href="...">
              <img src="..." alt="" class="avatar"/>
         </a>
    </p>

 </li>
 </ul>
```

and the positioning is floating:

```
 ul { list-style:none; }
 ul li {width:450px; margin-top:20px; padding:10px; float:left; }
 ul li img.avatar { position:relative; top:0px; left:50px; width:55px; height:55px;}
```

but with this the position of the image is not relative to the li.
How can i position the image relative to the li ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the `li` either `position: relative`, `fixed` or `absolute` to make it a "starting point" for relatively positioned children.